# AngularJS ui-select multiple default choice

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I've a problem with ui-select multiple. I need to set default value but I can't do it. I'm using a custom component of ui-select:

```
<input-form-wrapper input-ctrl="$ctrl">
  <ui-select ng-if="$ctrl.isMultiple"
    skip-focusser="true"
    ng-model="$ctrl.uiSelectValue"
    multiple
    id="{{$ctrl.name}}"
    name="{{$ctrl.name}}"
    ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()"
    ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled" 
    theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}">
     {{($ctrl.shortMatchElement === 'true') ? $item.code : $item.uiSelectDisplayField}}
            </ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices
            ui-disable-choice="option.status == 'disabled'"
            repeat="option as option in $ctrl.options | filter: {uiSelectDisplayField: $select.search}">
            <div ng-bind-html="option.uiSelectDisplayField"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </input-form-wrapper>
```

I'm using it in this way:

```
<my-ui-select 
                json-options="$ctrl.myModelList"
                is-disabled="$ctrl.myModelDisabled"
                ng-model="$ctrl.myModel" 
                value-field="item" 
                empty-option="false"
                is-multiple="true"
                ng-change="$ctrl.onMyModelSelect()">
            </my-ui-select>
```

I'm initializing the component in the subscribe function of http request:

```
for (let item in jsonResp) {
    tmp.push({ value: jsonResp[item].description, id: jsonResp[mmt].id, code: jsonResp[item].code, status: jsonResp[item].isDisabled == "true" ? "disabled" : "", uiSelectDisplayField: jsonResp[item].description});
}
 this.myModelList= tmp;
 this.myModel.push(this.myModelList[0]);
```

Though the model (this.myModel) is correctly initialized, the value isn't showed in the input. 
Is a mistake in code? Can you suggest me a solution?
Thanks

EDIT:
This is the component for my-ui-select:

```
let myUiSelectComponent = {
    'restrict': 'E',
    'bindings': angular.merge({}, baseBindings, {
        placeholder: "@",
        valueField: "@",
        displayField: "@",
        jsonOptions: "<",
        url: "<",
        emptyOption: "<",
        isDisabled: "<",
        isMultiple: "<",
        autoSelectFirstOption: "<",
        onRefresh: "&",
        onUpdateOptions: "&",
        shortMatchElement: "@"
    }),
    template,
    controller,
    require: {
        model: 'ngModel'
    }
};

export default myUiSelectComponent;
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your component? not just html

Comment: write like this 
`for (let item in jsonResp) {
    tmp.push({ value: jsonResp[item].description, id: jsonResp[mmt].id, code: jsonMeterModelType[item].code, status: jsonResp[item].isDisabled == "true" ? "disabled" : "", uiSelectDisplayField: jsonResp[item].description});
}
 this.myModelList= tmp;
 this.myModel = this.myModelList[0];` Hope it helps